# How to overcome special characters in Rss feed in android?

Tags: android

i have `rss feed` when sax parsing the rss feed . it can't parse
the  entire feed due to some special characters problem like `&` and `€”`.
how to overcome this problem and display entire feed `(item)data` in `strings`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parser's encoding to `utf-8`. Also, please add some context for a more specific help.